# WEKA K-Means Clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, weka, k-means

Can anybody explain what the output of the K-Means clustering in WEKA actually means.

For example

```
kMeans


Number of iterations: 9

Within cluster sum of squared errors: 9434.911100488926

Missing values globally replaced with mean/mode

Cluster centroids:

                  Cluster#
Attribute         Full Data          0          1                           
                      (400)      (310)       (90)
=================================================
competency134        0.0425     0.0548          0  
competency207        0.0425     0.0548          0  
competency263          0.01     0.0129          0  
competency264          0.01     0.0129          0  
competency282          0.01     0.0129          0  
competency289          0.01     0.0129          0
```

What do the numbers in the columns actually mean, it says cluster centroids above the table but how is it possible to determine what the centroids of the two clusters are ?

If anybody could explain what the numbers mean I would be most grateful.

If anybody has any ideas how to complete a silhouette evaluation of the clusters found that would also be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The first column gives you the overall population centroid. The second and third columns give you the centroids for cluster 0 and 1, respectively. Each row gives the centroid coordinate for the specific dimension.

I believe you need to brush up on your [K-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). Finding the centroids is an essential part of the algorithm. The centroids are a result of a specific run of the algorithm and are not unique - a different run may generate a different centroid set.

Please see [Michael Abernethy's description of Weka clustering](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-weka2/index.html?ca=drs-) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Just a first step,

1. Save the plot from the visualize tab as an arff file.
2. Open it with weka and click edit, you will automatically see in which cluster each instance belongs.
3. Copy this table to excel (to visualize easier)
4. Use excel or matlab to find silhoutte, cohesion, separation with the classic methods.

Comment: i tried but I could only see the data but not cluster number?

Comment: This work!! No need to apply the filter. Just save the file from weka cluster visualize pane as an arff file and open in weka. A new attribute named "cluster" is created.

Answer (score 0):

First the clustering is a descriptive statistical methods.
Second, the algorithm Kmeans required to enter the number of clusters beforehand, to find the optimal number of clusters, several statistical methods.
Third, the centroids of the numerical data are the arithmetic average of the data that makes the clusters.So these data are representing the group data.

Answer (score -1):

Use the most frequent value for an attribute in a cluster if the attribute is nominal.
    Use the average value for an attribute in a cluster if the attribute is numeric.
    Check [this link](http://www.lifl.fr/~urruty/enseign/introWeka.pdf) for more details.